# How to enable or disable a field in grocery

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm developing a form and need to enable or disable a field depending on the answer given.
Attached screen. When choosing whether to enable the field below, NO disables it.

Thanks for the reply.

[image]

Comment: Could you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this (using jquery hide and show):

---

You have to include jquery first in you file to make it work;

HTML:

```
         <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <input type="radio" class="radiobutton" name="select" value="yes" /> yes
        <input type="radio" class="radiobutton" name="select" value="no" />no
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
```

> Working example  https://jsfiddle.net/prohit0/zfjsmn59/22/

SCRIPT:

```
       <script>

         $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){

            if($(this).attr("value")=="yes"){
               //id is the id of the elemnt to hide
               $('input[id="name"]').show();
            }else {
            $('input[id="name"]').hide();
         }
        });
    });
   </script>
```

> http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/show-hide-divs-based-on-radio-button-selection-in-jquery.php